# Accessing object in another javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have two JS files

Player.js where I create a Media

```
(function() {

function Media(){
        this.url = "";
}

Media.prototype.setURL = function(url){
    this.url = url;
    alert("setURL="+this.url);
}

})();
```

Another file is Main.js where I access this Media as shown below

```
var media = new Media();
Main.keyDown = function(){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

    switch(keyCode){
       case tvKey.KEY_1:
            alert("Key 1 pressed");
            media.setURL("1-link");
            break;
    }
};
```

I have a index.html where I have included these scripts

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/dash-player.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/Main.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I am getting error while accessing this Media from Main.js as shown below

```
[JS ERROR]:
File:           Main.js
Line No:        3
Error Detail:   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Media
```

I have tried various things but since I am new to Javascript till now unable to get this resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Media` is only defined inside the IIFE in `Player.js`. Remove the `(function() { ... })();` wrapper.

Comment: Or better yet, keep it, and be sure to only export the symbols you need to export. (In this case, of course, that's the same thing as there's just `Media`...)

Comment: Yes, keeping the namespace make sure the prototype cannot be modified by external code. Basically, all plugins are usually done this way. I think he should keep it, but make it return the object and save it. See my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekDixit Your "elegance" was the the thing that was causing your code not to work. Perhaps before using syntax that you don't fully understand you should start a bit simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var Media = (function() {

function Media(){
        this.url = "";
}

Media.prototype.setURL = function(url){
    this.url = url;
    alert("setURL="+this.url);
}

return Media;

})();
```

Then you will keep the separated namespace for the Media prototype, but you can access the Media object from oustide to instanciate it.
I did not test this code, but I used to do that when implementing modules or plugins.

---

Maybe a little explanation about the `(function(){})()` syntax :

- the first `(` means you create a namespace : all variables setup inside will not exist outside. In contrast, outside variables will be accessible can be modified.
- the function `function(){}` is your function code. You can notice that it returns the 'Media' Object you just created.
- the `)` means you close the namespace.
- and the last `()`means you execute the previous code (aka the namespace code `(function(){})`. Since this code return the Media object, you can save it to a accessible-from-outside variable (aka the `var Media =` at the beginning).

Hope it is clear enough...

Comment: Erm... this doesn't stop people from doing `Media.prototype.somethingNew = function()...`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : In this use case, I guess you are right. It only allows you to create local variables like private counters or flags. Usually, instead of returning the Object, I extend jquery within the namespace by adding a function that instantiates the Object `$.extend({myJqfunc:function(){ var foo= new Media()}});` This prevents from modifying the prototype, right ?

Comment: Yes. But who are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : In the open source world ? Nobody. But I do some javascript modules at my job. I release them for other teams to use/embed them. As I am in charge of quality of these, I need to make sure other teams will not modify them, even not in purpose. And if they want to, they have to modify my own code, which liberates me from the responsability...

Comment: But I agree : it is a really particular scenario. ;)

Comment: As I say before, the main purpose is to avoid collision with other plugins that may use same "global" variables...